# Why is stripping a newline character in Python creating a blank space as a list item?

Tags: python-3.x, newline

I have the following code:

```
# File declaration.

infileS = open("single.dat", 'r')
infileD = open("double.dat", 'r')
infileT = open("triple.dat", 'r')
infileHR = open("homerun.dat", 'r')
infileAB = open("atbat.dat", 'r')
infileP = open("player.dat", 'r')


# Fill up the lists.
single = infileS.read()
double = infileD.read()
triple = infileT.read()
homerun = infileHR.read()
atbat = infileAB.read()
player = infileP.read()

single = [item.rstrip() for item in single]
double = [item.rstrip() for item in double]
triple = [item.rstrip() for item in triple]
homerun = [item.rstrip() for item in homerun]
atbat = [item.rstrip() for item in atbat]
player = [item.rstrip() for item in player]

print (single)
```

What prints:

```
['5', '', '3', '', '1', '0', '', '1', '2', '', '6', '', '9', '', '2', '0', '', '4', '', '7']
```

I don't want the '' items. What have I done wrong and what can I do to fix this?

All the .dat files are simple Notepad lists of numbers. The "single.dat" is a list of numbers with "enter" putting them on different lines (with no lines in between), and looks like: (minus, of course, the spaces between the paragraphs containing those numbers)

```
5 

3 

10 

12 

6 

9 

20 

4 

7
```

Comment: Can you show the files you are reading? That would be quite helpful to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empty strings (`''`) are what's left over if you `strip` something that's all whitespace (or possibly they were empty to start with). The easiest way to eliminate these is to use the fact that `''` is falsy, so you can remove them right there in your list comprehensions by adding `if item.strip()`.

**The problem** is that you're iterating over the output of `file.read()`, which is *a single string*. Strings in Python are iterable, but this means that when you iterate over them, you iterate over each character. So what you're doing is stripping each individual character and adding it to your list--so all your newlines turn into empty strings, rather than being stripped out like I think you intended.

To fix it, use the fact that file objects are also iterable, and iterate line-by-line. This is the idiomatic way to read a file line-by-line in Python (using a [context manager](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types) rather than a lone `open` call):

```
with open('single.dat') as f:
    for line in f:
        dosomething(line)
```

So, use that pattern along with some filtering in your list comprehension, and you'll be all set:

```
with open('single.dat') as f:
    single = [line.strip() for line in f if line.strip()]
```

Comment: Its also worth point out that `file.read()` pulls everything into a single string, which is why iterating over it is giving `'1','0'` instead of `'10'` as the OP likely wants.

Comment: To Lego's point it would cost even less if you put it in a `with` statement.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Yes indeed. I was just in the midst of rewriting this to address the most pertinent problem (that one) first. :-)

Answer (score -1):

It might be easiest to just filter out the ''.  For instance:

```
>>> list = ['', 'cat', 'dog', '']
>>> filter(None, list)
['cat', 'dog']
```